# Java memory usage - having same space

Tags: java

I came across this question and wondering how is this true!
Consider the following snippet of code:

```
int num = 14; 
int num2 = 3242424324; 
String place = "Gilbert, Arizona"; 
String txt = null;
```

From a Java perspective, all of these variables take up the same amount of space. Why is this?
I am not able to digest that all of them will take same space.

Comment: "From a Java perspective, all of these variables take up the same amount of space"--Where did you find this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They don't, exactly.  `place` is a *reference* to an object on the heap which can be bigger than just an `int`, but the reference itself is still just four bytes, the same as an `int`.  If you looked all the way through the object you'd find more memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

All references are the same size, no matter what their type is.

What you need to know is an object sits on the heap and does not have a name. Therefore, you have no way to access an object except through a reference. And because objects come in all different shapes and sizes they consume varying amounts of memory.